# cannot get method to write to output file correctly and cant edit

Tags: c#

Here is my Main Method

```
static void Main()
    {
        int id, age, exp;
        double avgAge, avgExp, ageSum = 0, expSum = 0, empSum = 0;
        char type;
        double total = 0;

        OpenFiles();
        PrintReportHeadings();
        while ((lineIn = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            empSum++;
            ParseLineIn(out id, out type, out age, out exp);
            UpdateTotals(ref ageSum, ref expSum, age, exp);
            string eligibility = GetEligibility(type, age, exp);
            PrintDetailLine(id, type, age, exp, eligibility);

        }

        avgAge = CalcAvg(ageSum, empSum, out total);
        avgExp = CalcAvg(expSum, empSum, out total);
        PrintAvg(avgAge, avgExp);
        CloseFiles();
    }
```

Here is my PrintAvg Method:

```
static void PrintAvg(double avgAge, double avgExp)
    {
        fileOut.Write("\nAvg\t  {0:f1}  {1:f1}", avgAge, avgExp);
    }
```

And my output file in VisualStudio

```
    Employee Report               

 ID  Age   Exp    Eligibility 
---- ---   ---    ----------- 
1235  45    20    lack of exp age
2536  55    21    lack of exp age
5894  60    30    lack age
4597  75    35    can retire
2597  35    10    lack of exp age
5689  40    20    lack of exp age
5489  55    39    lack age
5872  60    40    can retire
5569  55    25    can retire
5566  80    20    lack of exp
8865  59    35    can retire
5598  65    35    can retire
```

And then My output file again in notepad...

```
            Employee Report               

 ID  Age   Exp    Eligibility 
---- ---   ---    ----------- 
1235  45    20    lack of exp age
2536  55    21    lack of exp age
5894  60    30    lack age
4597  75    35    can retire
2597  35    10    lack of exp age
5689  40    20    lack of exp age
5489  55    39    lack age
5872  60    40    can retire
5569  55    25    can retire
5566  80    20    lack of exp
8865  59    35    can retire
5598  65    35    can retire
Avg   57.0  27.5
```

notepad shows the averages, and when i edit the PrintAvg method to try and get a line break to lower Avg line down one, it has no effect. How do i fix this?

Comment: why not use WriteLine?

Comment: I did go ahead and use

Comment: is your proble solve? can i post an answer for point? :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses \r\n as its newline character. So maybe you should try writing **\r\n** to get your desired number of newlines.

```
static void PrintAvg(double avgAge, double avgExp)
{
    fileOut.Write("\r\nAvg\t  {0:f1}  {1:f1}", avgAge, avgExp);
}
```

Comment: Or even better: Environment.NewLine